# id3 byte order mark in unicode

Tags: java, id3, unicode-string, byte-order-mark

I am working on id3V2.3 in java, I already change the textencoding to unicode using setTextEncoding. The problem is I can't find the method to change the BOM to little endian. I checked the ID3 tag I generated, it seems like they add FE FF in the beginning of the frame body string by default. I wanna change it to FF FE as little endian. If anyone know how to deal with it? Thank you so much!
PS: Is that the issue of unicode or id3 ? I can't find any method related to BOM setting in the ID3 java packages.

Comment: Could you narrow down your problem a little bit with concrete examples? First, what is the goal of the program you're writing (is it for reading tags, generating them or both)? Second, why do you need to change the BOM? Are you using a library (it's a bit confusing as you're saying "I generated" followed by "they add FE FF", so who generates what? who's "they"?) To my knowledge, ID3V2 tags are not a part of the Java SDK...